# setState problem facing when clicking to a button which is not changing the name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change the name from Monalisa to Leo nardo when I click on the button. but it is not working. What to do?

```
class Welcome extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.statee = {
      name: "Monalisa",
    };
  }

  nameChanger(a) {
    this.setState({ name: a });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.statee.name}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.nameChanger.bind(this, "Leo Nardo")}>
          Click Me
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Welcome;
```

Comment: this.statee should not be changed,

Comment: Yes I know I used statee not state, a reason is behind this, so give me solutions please

Comment: If `this.statee` can't be changed, what can? Is it kind of puzzle? What are the rules? Can you use normal state?

Comment: `nameChanger(a) {
    this.statee.name = a;
  }` should do the job. Although `setState`is there for a reason ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have typo twice, `state` instead of `statee`:

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "Monalisa"
  };

  nameChanger(a) {
    this.setState({ name: a });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.nameChanger.bind(this, "Leo Nardo")}>
          Click Me
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```